# In React, is it a good/bad idea to pass text thru as a prop to the component?

Tags: reactjs, text, components

For example, let's say you have a component that you're going to reuse many times in your app.

So you set it up to receive different/unique texts, multiple h2s and multiple ps as props.

```
const Sets = ({ oneH, twoH, threeH, oneP, twoP, threeP }) => {
  return (
    <div className="sets">
      <div>
        <h3>{oneH}</h3>
        <p>{oneP}</p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3>{twoH}</h3>
        <p>{twoP}</p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3>{threeH}</h3>
        <p>{threeP}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And then you use it as such:

```
<Sets
          oneH="Blue Skies"
          twoH="Good Times"
          threeH="Hotels, Etc."
          oneP="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, veniam voluptatibus."
          twoP="Different lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, veniam voluptatibus."
          threeP="Unique lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, veniam voluptatibus."
/>
```

Is there too much text in the  usage of it and is it too clunky? Is there some better way?

Comment: Looks quite normal to me

Comment: Agreed, typical presentational component pattern, though I would suggest using better named props. If there is no issue then perhaps this question is better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you are simply looking for recommendations & suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking it up even more, and putting the text sets into a JS array.

To make the source text more readable:

```
const texts = [
    {
       h:"abc",
       p:"123"
    },
    {
     ...
    }
]
```

And then pass this into your `Sets` element:

```
<Sets texts={texts} />
```

And then in the `Sets`, iterate the `texts`:

```
const Sets = ({ texts }) => {
  return (
    <div className="sets">
      {texts.map(({h,p}) => (
      <div>
        <h3>{h}</h3>
        <p>{p}</p>
      </div>
      )
    </div>
  );
};
```

This allows you to edit the source texts really easily in one place; it can even be loaded dynamically from an external source.

The single `texts` prop makes it easier to pass it in as you can see.

And finally the iteration allows you to escape having to type every single prop!

Comment: Good suggestion. Thank you, Tobin.

Comment: Please mark it as correct if it has helped you